# Correct jquery lib for supporting drag and drop of elements?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery development. I need to get drag and drop support for some elements, and I found this library provides what I need:

http://jqueryui.com/

is this a good choice? I'm not sure if there are any technical pitfalls, a better library to use for this, etc. The minified js file (with all features) is pretty large ~200kb, I'll have to cut down on that by using their custom config stuff,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, JQUI is a solid library. I've written several projects in it, and it's been a treat. As far as file size, most libraries are nontrivial these days, but for the jQuery UI project, try downloading only those pieces of the project you need. You'll have a much smaller footprint.